# How to use SafariDriver with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, safari

I am testing on Selenium WebDriver on SafariDriver.

I obtain this message in the beginning:

```
SafariDriver Launcher

[  0.024s] [safaridriver.client] Connecting to SafariDriver browser extension...
[  0.033s] [safaridriver.client] This will fail if you have not installed the latest SafariDriver extension from
http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
[  0.033s] [safaridriver.client] Extension logs may be viewed by clicking the Selenium [✓] button on the Safari toolbar
[  0.082s] [safaridriver.client] Connected to extension
[  0.083s] [safaridriver.client] Requesting extension connect to client at ws://localhost:36850
```

And after I obtain this message error:

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request POST /tunnel/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2dlbmVyb3NpdHktZGVtby5iaXNub2RlLmZyOjgyL2NhbXBhZ25lLWRlLWRvbi10cmVlLWxhYi5odG1s/product/23/form_key/JEQ8UWdbycz65baM/.

Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

For launching Safari I use:

```
Webdriver driver = new SafariDriver()
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: So what is `baseUrl`?

Comment: Hi baseUrl is the URL for the site.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the safaridriver.safaridriverxtz from the provided link and then double click it (click trust) and enable it as an extension for your Safari.

Restart and it should work (although I am running into other issues with it here...).

Answer (score 0):

Configure and enable Safari WebDriver:

- If you are on [macOS v10.13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_High_Sierra) (High Sierra) and later run 'safaridriver --enable' command in terminal.
- Open the Safari browser and follow the below steps:

  - Safari → *Preferences* then on the *Advanced* tab, select *'Show Develop menu in menu bar'*
  - From the menu bar, choose *Develop* → *'Allow Remote Automation'*